# Select where not null or empty in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I modified a model so it includes a new field, such as...

`field :url, :type => String`

I use activeadmin, so when I create a new entry `@model.url` is empty, and in entries created before changing the schema it's nil. How do I select both? I have tried:

```
# Returns nils and strings
Model.where(:url.ne => "").count 

# Returns strings and ""
Model.where(:url.ne => nil).count

# Returns strings, nils and ""
Model.where(:url.ne => ["", nil]).count
```

Or, if there's a best practice for this kind of scenario please let me know.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try

```
Model.where(:url.nin => ["", nil]).count
```

It works even when `url = nil`

Comment: I agree, this is the real answer and should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: In case you just want to check for entries where a field is not nil: `Model.where(:field.ne=>nil)`

Answer (score 98):

Try

```
Model.where(:url.ne => "", :url.exists => true).count
```

see [Mongoid Symbol Operators](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#symbol)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Model.nin(url: ['', nil])
```